# Iptable ubunto allow multiple specfic ip's to a specific port, drop the rest?

Tags: tcp, firewall, iptables

Wanting to do something like this

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s $IP_1 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT ! -s $IP_2 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT ! -s $IP_3 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j DROP
```

Where the server port is the same for all, but the allowed ip's can be different.... from what I know of iptables this wouldn't work as IP_3 would be dropped from the first rule... so how do I get something like this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm would this work?

```
iptables -A INPUT -s $IP_1 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $IP_2 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $IP_3 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport $SERVER_PORT -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

Those rules will drop all tcp packets destined for $SERVER_PORT. The first rule says if the source ip address isn't equal to $IP_1 then drop it. No further processing is done, since the rule was correctly matched. If the ip address is equal to $IP_1, then it will go to the second rule which will drop it for the same reason, assuming $IP_1 != $IP_2. In fact all tcp packets destined for $SERVER_PORT will be dropped without ever getting to rule 3.

Instead, do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s $IP_1 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $IP_2 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $IP_3 -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Remember to flush the rules first if you have no other rules: iptables -F.

Comment: lol... thanks.. well your solution is what I wanted to know anyway, mine was just an example of how I wanted it to work, but yeh I can see now how it would drop the IP_1 on the next rule for IP_2 :D

Comment: How safe is it to try that rule though... I mean "iptables -A INPUT -j DROP" at the end.. won't that just drop all connections that don't meet the above rules? I only want it to drop all other ip's  for that specific dport that don't meet the rules.. while the rest of my server ports will work as normal....??

Comment: Yes that's correct - it will drop all other packets - I thought that's what you meant when you said "drop the rest". If you want to keep other ports open, e.g. ssh, then replace the last line with: iptables -A INPUT --dport $SERVER_PORT -j DROP

In general, anytime you are configuring the firewall, you want to be able to log in to the console directly, as opposed to ssh, in case something goes wrong.